# Can Ethereum be shut down?

Tags: nodes, attacks

How realistic is to shutdown Ethereum network, so the smart contracts won't be executed anymore?

Are there any practical or theoretical destructive ways to do it? Intentionally or not?

Like a multiple major security threats, DDoS attacks, injecting malicious nodes or governments will start blocking the nodes. Is it even possible?

Comment: This question is quite subjective and speculative for a quality Q&A site.  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/366/what-methods-could-a-government-use-to-shutdown-bitcoin has answers that I would suggest.

Comment: Could be a bit subjective, but it could be also creative. I've read this [article](http://www.newsereum.com/newsereum/can-ethereum-shut/), so I was hoping somebody will come up with some good answer. This was inspired by [Where there any attempts to create a global decentralized AI?](http://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1477/8) question from which I wanted to link it back to this one (to show in general that it cannot), if this would be answered ([access link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence)).

Comment: IMO Reddit is a place to go for Subjective questions, may be on the Ethereum channel itself. As long as we have a guidelines here what/how to/not to ask, we cannot encourage these questions here.

Comment: Do you suggest to narrow it down to some specific disaster? Which one would be less subjective?

Comment: @kenorb Can you repost the ling related to the decentralized artificial intelligence?

Comment: @Sebi Could you rephrase? You mean link? It's above, but you need to click on the 'access link' first (then click Visit), because it's in private beta currently.

Comment: @kenorb My bad. I had to make an account to view the question (ai is still in the alpha stages).

Comment: Does 'No' answer your question? Of course you can ban specific traffic or shut down the internet, but this wont prevent users from running Ethereum.  Maybe you could specify what exactly your thoughts are leading to that question? And also, what kind of answer you expect?